# Obter valor da div

Tags: php

Quero obter o valor da `div` quando clico. O problema é que cria uma `div` no `foreach`. Quero obter o `id`, para depois passar essa valor para outra página e utilizar para fazer um SELECT na base de dados SQLite.

```
$array_resultadoss = array(); //array   
$array_resultadoss=select($dir, $base, $i);
$titless = ""; //variable inicialize 

foreach($array_resultadoss as $key =>$value){
    $titless .= "<div class=dois>".$value['id']."</div>";//save in variable value
}

echo" 
    <td class='td_today'>
        <div class=divday style='cursor:pointer' onclick='popup(\"_popup_cal.php?jour=$i&moisEcris=$months[$moisaff]&annee=$year&mois=$month&txttitle=$txttitle&txtstart=$txtstart&txtend=$txtend&txtdescription=$txtdescription&maj=$maj&clean=1&numevent=$numevent\",400,300)';>
        ".$titless."</div>
    </td>";
}
```

Comment: Como você está tentando recuperar o valor em `_popup_cal.php`?

Comment: Pelo metodo GET

Comment: Pelo método GET tens de passar a variável no link.

Comment: Certo e passo por aqui  onclick='popup(\"_popup_cal.php?id=$key&jour=$i&moisEcris=$months[$moisaff]&annee=$year&mois=$month&txttitle=$txttitle&txtstart=$txtstart&txtend=$txtend&txtdescription=$txtdescription&maj=$maj&clean=1&numevent=$numevent\",400,300)'

Comment: Onde, não vejo ai nem `$array_resultadoss` nem `$key` nem `$value`...

Comment: Nao é o id=$key?Então como devo fazer?

Comment: Deixa-me ver se percebi tu queres que cada elemento de `$array_resultadoss` tenha uma `<td class='td_today'>`?

Comment: Tenho so essa div que mostra todos os eventos da base de dados. Quero que ao clicar na div, me de o id (valor) no registo que clicei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, aconselho que você refatore o seu código, a lógica não está legal. Mas mantendo o que você já fez, acredito que a forma de conseguir o que você espera é gerando a função `popup()` do Javascript para cada `<div>`. Fiz os ajustes no código e ficou assim:

```
$array_resultadoss = array();
$array_resultadoss = select($dir, $base, $i);
$titless = '';

foreach ($array_resultadoss as $key => $value) {
    $titless .= "<div class=dois onclick='popup(\"_popup_cal.php?jour=$i&moisEcris=$months[$moisaff]&annee=$year&mois=$month&txttitle=$txttitle&txtstart=$txtstart&txtend=$txtend&txtdescription=$txtdescription&maj=$maj&clean=1&numevent=$numevent&num_div={$value['id']}\",400,300)';>" . $value['id'] . '</div>';
}

echo "<td class='td_today'>
          <div class=divday style='cursor:pointer'>
              " . $titless . "
          </div>
      </td>";
```

Então em `_popup_cal.php` você terá `$_GET['num_div']`